# Search for cells missing specified text and then add it

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet with alphanumeric entries in Column A.  All entries should have the same six digit ending but some don't.  I found a macro that adds specific text to the end of each cell in a column but it adds it to ALL cells. The macro I'm trying to adjust is:

```
Sub AppendToExistingOnRight()
 Dim c As Range
 For Each c In Selection
 If c.Value <> "" Then c.Value = c.Value & "-368341"
 Next
 End Sub
```

I need an IF statement to say,

```
if c.Value **does not contain** "-368341" Then c.Value = c.Value & "-368341"
```

I just don't know what terminology to use.  I know this is probably simple but I've searched for a while and can't find a simple solution.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
If c.Value <> "" And InStr(c, "-368341") = 0 Then c.Value = c.Value & "-368341"
```

instead of your If statement.